# Query a list of subsites as a sharepoint list or set of rows?

Tags: 2010, site

We have a bunch of projects each represented by a Sharepoint 2010 subsite.

We would like to store and track metadata and run reports across this list of subsites.

Is there any way to query and maintain a current list of subsites? In excel? Into a regular SharePoint list?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to leverage the [SPDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spdatasource.aspx) control and it's `Webs` [DataSourceMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spdatasource.datasourcemode.aspx).

After creating the datasource, you can display the list of subsites using [SPGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx) or [DataFormWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataviewwebpart.aspx) (where you can use XSLT to format the output) or any other control which can grab data from *IDataSource*.

Please have a look at the following article for details and example:

- http://solutionizing.net/2008/09/09/spdatasource-mystery-modes-webs-listoflists/